# "Type interface is not known to the MapperRegistry" exception using mybatis

Tags: java, ibatis, mybatis

I'm setting up mybatis using annotations, and getting this helpful exception

> org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException:
>   Type interface org.foo.Bar is not
>   known to the MapperRegistry

[Googling it](http://www.google.co.il/search?hl=en&q=BindingException%3a+%22Type+interface+is+not+known+to+the+MapperRegistry%22&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) doesn't find anything, nor the user guide. What am I missing?

Comment: I love Google. 5 minutes after asking this, the Google link I posted points only to this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, got it - this is happening because I was using a XML file for the configuration, and annotations for the mappers themselves - and mybatis doesn't find mapper annotations when using an XML config.

See this [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264485/mybatis-using-mapper-interfaces-with-xml-config-for-global-parameters).

Answer (score 25):

just for anyone who ended up here because they're new to mybatis
<strike>http://www.mybatis.org/core/configuration.html</strike>
http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html

in the config file mappers section

```
<mappers>
<mapper class="my.package.com.MyClass"/>
</mappers>
```

this will have you up and running with a config.xml and annotated interfaces

Answer (score 12):

add **Mapper** class to your SqlSessionFactory Configuration as this:

```
SqlSessionFactory factory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder()
            .build(reader);

//very import
factory.getConfiguration().addMapper(BarMapper.class);

SqlSession sqlSession = factory.openSession();
```

Answer (score 3):

In your mapper.xml file mapper's namespace should be the path to the mapper interface.

for example:

```
<mapper namespace="com.mapper.LineMapper">
<select id="selectLine" resultType="com.jiaotong114.jiaotong.beans.Line">
select * from bus_line where id = #{id}
</select>
</mapper>
```

your mapper interface should be in com.mapper package and the name of it is LineMapper.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your mapper.xml file is using the incorrect namespace (perhaps because of a copy paste error).

For instance, let's say you have a Java interface called `MyEntityMapper.java` that *should* be linked to a mybatis mapper xml config called `MyEntityMapper.xml`:

**MyEntityMapper.java**

```
package my.mappers;

public interface MyEntityMapper {
    MyEntity getById(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

**MyEntityMapper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
                        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="non.existent.package.NonExistentMapper">

    <resultMap id="MyEntityResultmap" type="MyEntity">
        <!-- some result map stuff here -->
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getByUuid" resultMap="MyEntityResultMap">
        <!-- some sql code here -->
    </select>
</mapper>
```

Notice that the `namespace` attribute on the `<mapper>` element in `MyEntityMapper.xml` is pointing to some non-existent mapper `non.existent.package.NonExistentMapper`, when really it should be pointing to `my.mappers.MyEntityMapper`.

Answer (score 1):

Type interface *org.domain.classmapper* is not known to the MapperRegistry

MyBatis throws this exception if the full package / class is not entered into the mapper xml namespace.

e.g. 
`<mapper namespace="classmapper">` causes exception, but

`<mapper namespace="org.domain.classmapper">` works

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when creating a shadowJar/bootJar for a spring boot project and
using org.springframework.boot gradle plugin

When the jars are zipped inside the bootJar myBatis may fail to find the XML configuration files and will throw the described exception

adding this block in the build.gradle file:

```
bootJar {
    requiresUnpack '**/MyProblematic.jar'
}
```

solved my problem