# mybatis: Using mapper interfaces with XML config for global parameters

Tags: java, orm, ibatis, mybatis

I like the XML notation for specifying global parameters such as connection strings. I also like Mapper annotations. When I try to combine the two, I get [this exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263832/type-interface-is-not-known-to-the-mapperregistry-exception-using-mybatis).

Is there a way to combine the two? I would like to use an XML file for the global configurations, but have mybatis take Mapper interfaces into account.

The problem is that SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build() takes either a Reader (which I want to use to pass the XML config), or a Configuration object (which I see has the `addMappers()` method that can help me) - but I don't understand how to combine the two.

Comment: I'd really like to know this! Adding the mapper Interfaces by hand isn't a suitable solution. How can we configure mappers in XML and using MapperInterfaces together without adding them by hand?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`factory.getConfiguration().addMapper(...);`

Answer (score 6):

When u create the **mapper interface** with the abstract methods having the exact method signature as the sql in the xml.

For eg. This was the namespace for the dao.xml which contained the actual query.

```
<mapper namespace=" com.mybatis.dao.EntityMapperInterface">
    <select id="selectEmployeeWithId" parameterType="Long"
        resultType="com.mybatis.domain.Employee">
        select id,name from employee where 1=1
        <if test="_parameter != null"> 
            AND id=#{id} 
        </if>
        order by id
    </select>
```

It will be mapped in the **interface com.mybatis.dao.EntityMapperInterface**

```
public interface EntityMapperInterface {
    public List<Employee> selectEmployeeWithId(Long id);
```

**Mybatis-config file**

```
<mappers>
    <mapper resource="com/mybatis/mappers/EntityMapper.xml" />
</mappers>
```

How do u call it from the Action class/Servlet?
When u have the SqlSession initialized,

```
EntityMapperInterface emi = session.getMapper(EntityMapperInterface.class);
List eList = emi.selectEmployeeWithId(1);
```

Comment: Where is this mentioned in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was because the name space in mybatis mapper file and the package of the mapper interface were not matching.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, It helps me a lot. I use no XML config mybatis with spring. Here's what I do:

```
SqlSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.addMapper(AccountMapper.class);
factoryBean.setConfiguration(configuration);
return factoryBean.getObject();
```